# Replace IN query in the sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query. I need to replace the IN query

```
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1
  WHERE 
        FIELD2 LIKE '%SEARCH_DATA%'

        AND (CASE WHEN CONDITION1=TRUE THEN FIELD1
              ELSE 'TEXT1'
              END   IN ('TEXT1','TEXT2'))
```

Could you please let me know how to replace IN with the same condition.

Comment: Actually what you are trying to do?

Comment: What's your requirement exactly? Its confusing

Comment: replace `IN` with *what* exactly?

Comment: Why do you need to replace it?  The syntax looks okay (it is not how I would write it, but this syntax should do what you want).

Comment: As per the company standard we cannot use IN clause in the sql query then we need to find the alternate of the above query. We are filtering the data through the where condition.

Comment: @PankajSaha . . . Your company has ludicrous standards.  The `IN` is fine.  It is the `CASE` that should be forbidden in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: To forbid the usage of `IN` sounds completely stupid in my opinion. `IN` is made to get queries more readable, so why would anyobody in their right mind  shun it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE1
WHERE   CONDITION1 <> TRUE -- CONDITION1 = FALSE 
    OR  (FIELD1 = 'TEXT1' OR FIELD1 = 'TEXT2')
```

Answer (score 1):

This translates to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE FIELD2 LIKE '%SEARCH_DATA%'
AND
(
  (CONDITION1 = TRUE AND FIELD1 IN ('TEXT1','TEXT2'))
   OR CONDITION1 = FALSE
   OR CONDITION1 IS NULL
)
```

If CONDITION can only be TRUE or FALSE and not NULL, then we can simplify this to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE FIELD2 LIKE '%SEARCH_DATA%' AND (CONDITION1 = FALSE OR FIELD1 IN ('TEXT1','TEXT2'))
```

(otherwise we'd have to replace `CONDITION1 = FALSE` with `CONDITION1 = FALSE  OR CONDITION1 IS NULL`).

And without `IN` (though I like it better with `IN`):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1
WHERE FIELD2 LIKE '%SEARCH_DATA%' 
AND (CONDITION1 = FALSE OR FIELD1 = 'TEXT1' OR FIELD1 = 'TEXT2')
```